# What are the rules for using COLLATE in a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions, scripting, collation

I am putting a script together, that gives me the permissions on database objects.

```
SELECT  permission_order=710
       ,permission_type = 'Object Level Permissions'
       ,db = db_name(),
login_=null,
role_=dp.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,
Obj = sys.schemas.name + '.' + so.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,
Permission = permission_name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,
[script]=
'IF OBJECT_ID ('  + '''' + '['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + so.name + ']'  + '''' + ') IS NOT NULL ' + CHAR(10) + state_desc + 
' ' + permission_name + ' on ['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + so.name + '] to [' + dp.name + ']' collate Latin1_General_CI_AS + CHAR(10) +
'ELSE ' + CHAR(10) +
'print ' + '''['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + so.name + '] - does not exist'''
+ CHAR(13)

from sys.database_permissions a
INNER JOIN  sys.objects so on a.major_id = so.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas on so.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp on a.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
WHERE dp.name NOT IN ( 'public', 'guest')
AND a.class = 1
```

I want to use the word `collate` as few times as possible and still have a script that runs for multi-databases, multi-collations server.

How can I achieve that?
What is the rule for applying `collate`?

[image]

Comment: Aside: there's `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` to, well, use the default of the current database, which can save on some inappropriate hard-coding. (It probably wouldn't do any good in this particular case, but then, I don't see `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS` doing that either.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`COLLATE` operates *per predicate* or *per expression*, depending on context. `COLLATE` is mainly used to control how the string values are being compared or sorted. Hence it is most commonly used in `JOIN`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` predicates, as well as `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses (in which case it can be used per column / expression). It needs to be applied to string columns that could possibly have differing Collations. Non-string types (including XML) do not use `COLLATE`, and columns that are guaranteed to have the same Collation do not need it. For `JOIN`, `WHERE`, and `HAVING` predicates, it only *needs* to be specified on one side of the operator since the other side will be coerced into the specified Collation.

It *generally* wouldn't be used in a `SELECT` list unless there was a reason to change the Collation of the selected column / expression, which would mainly apply to `VARCHAR` data as you can change the Code Page, but I really don't see much application for this usage. The most likely reason to do this would be if the client requesting the data needs a different Code Page, but I can't think of a reason that this would ever be needed.

However, one reason to use it in the `SELECT` list (and possibly other places) is when doing string concatenation involving two or more columns that can potentially have mixed Collations. This scenario would apply to both `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` data. You shouldn't need to worry about single columns and string literals as the literals will be coerced into the Collation of the column.

Another reason you might need `COLLATE` in a `SELECT` list is when using `UNION`, `INTERSECT`, or `EXCEPT`, and the Collation between columns / expressions in the same position between at least two of the queries is not the same.

So, looking at your query:

1. You don't need `COLLATE` in these places:

   - `role_=dp.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,`
     because you are just selecting a single column, nothing is being mixed.
   - `Obj = sys.schemas.name + '.' + so.name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,`
     because both columns are database-level meta-data from the same database which is guaranteed to be the same Collation, plus a string literal that is already the database's default Collation (same as the two column's it is being concatenated with), but even if it wasn't already the same, it would be coerced into the Collation of the two columns. Only improvement here would be to prefix the literal with an upper-case `N` since the expression is `NVARCHAR` due to the schema names and object names being of type `sysname` which is an alias for `NVARCHAR(128)`.
   - `Permission = permission_name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,`
     because you are just selecting a single column, nothing is being mixed.
2. You *do* need `COLLATE` in the string concatenation because you are mixing database-level meta-data (which uses the database's default Collation) and system-level meta-data (i.e. `state_desc` and `permission_name`) which comes from the hidden `mssqlsystemresource` database and usually has a Collation of `Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS`. It should be fine to have `COLLATE` specified only once per expression since it should have the highest precedence and force both literals and columns into the stated Collation.

Finally, regarding *which* Collation to specify: `DATABASE_DEFAULT`, `CATALOG_DEFAULT`, or one of your choosing (such as you are doing here): given that you are working on `NVARCHAR` data (no chance of changing the Code Page / character set) and not using `COLLATE` for sorting or comparison (no chance of changing how the query works between different databases), it really doesn't matter; it's all the same in this particular scenario. You would use `DATABASE_DEFAULT` or `CATALOG_DEFAULT` if you needed the query (or that particular predicate or `ORDER` / `GROUP` item) to be sensitive to local database and change behavior depending on where the query is being executed.

Other notes:

1. I would suggested enclosing the result set column names in square brackets (i.e. `[permission_order]` instead of `permission_order`, `[role_]` instead of `role_`, etc).
2. You have `CHAR(13)` at the end which should be `CHAR(10)` like the rest of those newlines in that concatenation.
3. Even better would be to use `NCHAR(10)` *and* prefix each string literal piece of the concatenation with an upper-case `N` since you are concatenating `sysname` / `NVARCHAR` columns which will force the entire string into `NVARCHAR`, hence those `CHAR()` references and string literals are being implicitly converted anyway.
4. Also good would be to wrap the schema / object names in `QUOTENAME()` (and remove your explicit delimiters — `[` and `]` — in the string literals) as `QUOTENAME` has the benefit of escaping embedded delimiters.

Comment: When you say "per predicate" do you not mean "per expression"?

Comment: @usr Hi there. I believe "predicate". But to clarify in case I'm using terminology incorrectly, consider this simple example: `SELECT 1 FROM sys.all_objects WHERE [name] = N'objects' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2`. The predicate is both sides of the "x = y", and an expression is just one side, both "x" and "y", each being a separate expression, correct? If yes to both, then yes, per predicate since both sides need to be of the same Collation, so `COLLATE` will force both sides of the predicate, not just the expression it is directly attached to. Else you would get a Collation mismatch error.

Comment: I would say it's per expression and the collation propagates automatically throughout the query. Collation really is a part of the type system. `x COLLATE C1` is a different type than `x COLLATE C2`. Types in T-SQL are parameterized for example `numeric(a, b)` but also strings by their length and collation. All T-SQL expressions have a static type (int, bit, ...) even though you don't normally declare it. Types just flow. Like `var x = GetString();` in C# where x is string without you saying it.

Comment: @usr Re: your statement of "_it's per expression and the collation propagates automatically throughout the query._": Firstly, collation is not per-query, so it doesn't propagate out that far. It goes from `COLLATE` -> column -> string literal, all within an expression, _then_ when involved in a predicate, over to the other side of the predicate where it either matches, will coerce if needed _and_ possible, or will error if needed but not possible. Secondly, yes, _Collation_ is, on that level, per expression. BUT, this question is about _how to apply the `COLLATE` keyword_, which is different.

Comment: I did not mean to imply it is per query. It is per expression and there are many expressions in a query. It's not about predicates. It propagates, too, through computed columns (e.g. `select myString + 'x'`), groupings and other calculations.

Comment: @usr I believe you misunderstood what I was saying by focusing solely on the first sentence. I have stated, in several places, that `COLLATE` can be applied per expression. However, I re-read my answer and saw a few places that could be improved to reduce confusion, so I have updated it to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: I think your answer is great :)

Comment: @usr Thanks! And, thank you for bringing up the point about predicate vs expression. I knew, overall, what I had said, but had forgotten some of the specifics of how it was said. I think it is a clearer, better answer now, and that wouldn't have happened without this exchange.